# Button on website for taking screenshot

Tags: java, web, screenshot, java-web-start

Is there a way to take a screenshot/snip from a website?  The screenshot isn't of a website/URL specifically (so other things I've found such as html2canvas wouldn't work).

Basically, what would be ideal is pressing a button and having the user be able to use a sort-of Windows Snipping Tool, but instead of the user choosing whether to copy or save the snip afterwards, it would be automatically uploaded to the server as an image.

One of the things I was looking at is Java Web Start -- I haven't ever used it, but it seems that the java app is downloaded each time the user wants to use the app. Is there a way to accomplish this without the user needing to download anything?